# How to set default sorting in camunda tasklist?

Tags: camunda, tasklist

I'm trying to set default sorting order in camunda tasklist filter to asc by created date.

Found only [this suggestion](https://forum.camunda.org/t/change-the-default-task-sorting-criteria-for-task-list/17599) which says that I should use maven replacer plugin. But I would like to make it more elegant way. For example for tasklist localization I created file `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/webjars/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/config.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have web camunda with spring:
*org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp:3.4.2*

Added file *PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/webjars/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/defaultSorting.js*

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    var ngModule = angular.module('tasklist.defaultSorting', []);

    ngModule.config(['ViewsProvider', function (ViewsProvider) {
        ViewsProvider.registerDefaultView('tasklist.header', {
            id: 'default-sorting',
            priority: 50,
            template: "<script>angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('sorting-choice')).scope().changeOrder(0)</script>"
        });
    }]);

    return ngModule;
});
```

which set order needed order while loading of TaskList page.

To enable functionality in file you need to add customScripts in
*PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/webjars/camunda/app/tasklist/scripts/config.js*:

```
var camTasklistConf = {
    "locales": {
        "availableLocales": ["ru"],
        "fallbackLocale": "ru"
    },
    app: {
        name: 'App',
        vendor: 'Vendor'
    },
    customScripts: {
        ngDeps: ['tasklist.defaultSorting'],
        deps: ['defaultSorting'],
        paths: {
            'defaultSorting': 'scripts/defaultSorting'
        }
    }
};
```

Related documentation: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/webapps/cockpit/extend/configuration/#custom-scripts